# extract domain or domain with subdomain from a link?

Tags: php

i need a php function to extract domain with tld from a url or domain with tld and subdomain if there is.

example:

http://minova.tumblr.com/post/145515   >>  minova.tumblr.com

http://www.tumblr.com/about/1 >> tumblr.com

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php - special focus on 'host' and 'path'.

#### Example:

```
$var = "http://minova.tumblr.com/post/145515";
print_r(parse_url($var));
```

Outputs:

```
array (
  'scheme' => 'http',
  'host'   => 'minova.tumblr.com',
  'path'   => '/post/145515',
)
```

#### Example II:

```
$var = "http://minova.tumblr.com/post/145515";
print parse_url($var, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Outputs:

```
minova.tumblr.com
```