# How to extract domain name from url using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

If you searched in google scholar for example: [http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=filetype:pdf](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=filetype%3Apdf), you can see at the right side the download links for those with pdf (picture below).

[image]

How can I extract the domain name from the url using xslt? In the picture above, google scholar just displayed the domain names for the url (eg sciencenet.cn, unive.it). The url can be in http, https, ftp.

What I'm trying to achieve is like this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059707/extract-domain-or-domain-with-subdomain-from-a-link) but using xslt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAICT, the URL above returns an HTML document that is **not** a well-formed XML document - so it is not possible to process it using XSLT.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I am referring to the url of the search results. For example, in the first search result, the url is: http://bbs.sciencenet.cn/bbs/upload/15320200207j5.pdf, so I want to extract bbs.sciencenet.cn.

Comment: I am referring to the document returned by the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling around, I found the answer here: [Extracting Domain from URL in XSLT](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/XML/Q_21201982.html)

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="url_ini" select="/root/url"/>        
    <xsl:variable name="url_minus_http" select="substring-after($url_ini,'//')"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($url_minus_http,'/')"/>             
  </xsl:template>
```